# Pipe alignment/height issue

Tags: kitchens, drain, pipe

I have an issue involving the heights of the pipes under the sink. I recently installed a new deeper sink and the drain is much lower to the point that it is the same height as the pipe leading into the wall. This is causing water to stay in the drain in the sink. Is there any fixes to this issue without cutting a new lower hole in the wall pipe?

[image: diagram of sink and ubend]

Comment: Put a taller cabinet in to raise the sink.

Comment: Put a taller cabinet in to raise the sink.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there any fixes to this issue without cutting a new lower hole in the wall pipe?**

- reinstate the previous sink.
- replace the new sink with a new shallower one.
- raise the new sink higher.

The sensible choice may be to insert a new tee fitting lower in the wall pipe and remove or cap the higher one.